# Recover access to a juju env after losing the jenv file

Tags: juju

I have a juju environment comprised of three servers, setup via manual provider. After a hardware failure I lost the .jenv file for the manual environment. I still have the admin-user password and can login to the gui on that env, and I still have ssh access to the machines.

I've tried simply creating a new manual provider config.yaml and setting the admin-user password, but that's clearly not all that needs to be done, as juju still sees an unbootstrapped environment. Is there anyway to recover access to this environment?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to rebuild the .jenv file.  An example is given for openstack at [this blog](http://www.metaklass.org/how-to-recover-juju-from-a-lost-juju-openstack-provider/).  The procedure is quite detailed and I know the question is old, but I wanted to archive it for posterity.

I won't print everything on that blog, but just a quick-version.  Start with a boiler plate .jenv, as of this writing, use something like this:

```
user: admin  
password: test  
environ-uuid: ENVIRONMENT_UUID  
state-servers:  
- ip-address-of-your-bootstrap-node:17070

server-hostnames:  
- ip-address-of-your-bootstrap-node:17070

ca-cert: CA_CERT

bootstrap-config:  
  access-key: ""
  admin-secret: TO_BE_DEFINED
  agent-metadata-url: https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/
  api-port: 17070
  apt-http-proxy: http://squid.internal:3128
  apt-https-proxy: http://squid.internal:3128
  auth-mode: userpass
  auth-url: http://10.230.19.65:5000/v2.0
  authorized-keys: 
  bootstrap-addresses-delay: 10
  bootstrap-retry-delay: 5
  bootstrap-timeout: 600
  ca-cert: SECOND_CA_CERT
  ca-private-key: SECOND_CA_CERT_PRIVATE
  charm-store-auth: ""
  control-bucket: CONTROL_BUCKET
  default-series: ""
  development: false
  disable-network-management: false
  firewall-mode: instance
  image-metadata-url: http://x.x.x.x:80/swift/v1/simplestreams/data/
  image-stream: released
  logging-config: <root>=WARNING;unit=DEBUG
  lxc-clone-aufs: false
  name: USERNAME
  network: ""
  password: PASSWORD
  prefer-ipv6: false
  proxy-ssh: true
  region: region
  secret-key: ""
  set-numa-control-policy: false
  ssl-hostname-verification: true
  state-port: 37017
  syslog-port: 6514
  tenant-name: USERNAME
  test-mode: false
  tools-metadata-url: https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/
  type: openstack
  use-default-secgroup: true
  use-floating-ip: false
  username: USERNAME
  uuid: ENVIRONMENT_UUID
```

Then, modify as follows:

**environ-uuid** and **uuid** can be obtained from mongo on the bootstrap node as follows:

```
mongo --ssl -u admin -p $(grep oldpassword /var/lib/juju/agents/machine-0/agent.conf | awk -e '{print $2}') localhost:37017/admin
```

Once on the database, get your UUID:

```
juju:PRIMARY> db = db.getSiblingDB('juju')  
juju:PRIMARY> db.environments.find().pretty()

{ "_id" : "cc503d03-6933-47a7-8a16-4d1094a6593e"
```

The **control-bucket** and **first ca-cert** entry can be obtained from the database:

```
# look for 'ca-cert' in this mess of output, copy out into your file
# with 'begin' and 'end' blocks.  Look at another .jenv to get the
# right yaml format
juju:PRIMARY> db.settings.find().pretty()
```

The **second ca-cert and ca-private key** are on the bootstrap node at '/var/lib/juju/server.pem'

Everything else should be pretty self explanatory for what you sub in.  The password can be quite hard if you lost it, but if you did, that blog post has a detailed description of how to reverse it from the database.  See the blog for the long and dirty details, including how to access the VM on the backend of openstack if you lost your ssh access, etc.